# Formatting TOC in Latex

Tags: tables, tocloft, tocstyle

I am trying to create table of contents with each chapter title underlined. No luck so far. Can somebody help. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you want to commit such a typographical crime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this in your preamble:

```
\usepackage{titletoc,ulem}

      \titlecontents{chapter}[0em]{\smallskip\bfseries}%\vspace{1cm}%
      {\contentslabel[\uline{\chaptername~\thecontentslabel}]{0em}\hspace{5.6em}\uline}%
      {\renewcommand\thecontentslabel{\relax}\itshape\uline}%numberless%
      {\hfill\contentspage}[\medskip]%
```

Comment: Many thanks. One issue. It creates two separate ul one for "chapter" and another for "chapter title". Can it be modified to one single underline?

Comment: @MrMBB: Yes. Replace: you also have to underline the white space between label and title. Explicitly, `\hspace{5.6em}` with `\uline{\hspace{5.6em}}`. Maybe it would look nicer in this case to add a dot at the end of the label.